# Django filter by two fields rangement

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I have a model with two fields: `min_age`, `max_age`. And I need to filter it with Django Filters by range of two fields. How can I do that?

```
# models.py

class AdvertisementModelMixin(models.Model):
    min_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(80)
        ]
    )
    max_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(80)
        ]
    )
```

Comment: So exactly what are the inputs of the filter, and how would the filter work?

Comment: @willem-van-onsem I'm sending get request like `/?user_age=16`, and it will send me models whose age range is 16 years. For example, it should send model with `min_age=12`, `max_age=18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter with:

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, NumberFilter


class MyFilterSet(FilterSet):
    user_age = NumberFilter(field_name='user_age', method='filter_user_age')

    def filter_user_age(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.objects.filter(min_age__lte=value, max_age__gte=value)
```

or for nullable's:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import FilterSet, NumberFilter


class MyFilterSet(FilterSet):
    user_age = NumberFilter(field_name='user_age', method='filter_user_age')

    def filter_user_age(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.objects.filter(
            Q(min_age=None) | Q(min_age__lte=value),
            Q(max_age=None) | Q(max_age__gte=value),
        )
```

Comment: And what if fields are nullable? for example, `min_age=12`, `max_age=None` it should send me models with `min_age=12`, and `max_age` is unlimited